# why all behaves differently than a simple short circuiting condition

Tags: python

Why does `all` behave differently than `if` in this case?

```
In [1]: a = []

In [2]: if a and a[1]: # short circuiting -> no exception 
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: all((a, a[0])) # a[0] is evaluated before the condition is evaluated -> exception
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a381b7aa45b3> in <module>()
----> 1 all((a, a[0]))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [3]: all((a, a[0])) # a[0] is evaluated before the condition is evaluated -> exception
```

The difference is that when you call a function, Python evaluates all of the parameters and then passes in their values to the function. So here `a` and `a[0]` are evaluated to create a `tuple`. Then that `tuple` is passed to `all()` if it is created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

`all` iterates over its argument until it finds a false value. But you have to *create* that iterable first. In order to build a tuple, you first have to fully evaluate each element to put *in* the tuple: `all` only looks at the *results*.

For lazy evaluation of the elements, you need something that produces them on demand, for exampl using a generator:

```
 def things():
     yield a
     yield a[0]

 if all(things()):
      ...
```

`things` returns a `generator`, which will provide `a` and `a[0]` *on demand*. It doesn't do *anything* until then. Here, `all` will get the first value (`a`), and if it is false, never request the second value. If the second value is never requested, then the generator never bothers evaluating `a[0]`.